# Linux Drush install error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA' in phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/lib/Drush/Sql/Sqlmysql.php, line 56

Tags: drush

I tried installing Drush with both methods listed in the drush.org documentation. I think they might be conflicting with each other if that's possible.

When I run `composer global require drush/drush` all the components appear to install correctly. However when I change to a Drupal site (Using XAMPP, /opt/lampp/htdocs/sitefolder) and run `drush status` I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA' in
>   phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/lib/Drush/Sql/Sqlmysql.php on line 56
>   Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
>   [error] Error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA' in
>   phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/lib/Drush/Sql/Sqlmysql.php, line 56

I do have the following line in my ~/.bashrc:

`export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`

Unfortunately I don't know how to troubleshoot from here, as there doesn't seem to be an easy way to uninstall Drush via the main method (http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/), which didn't seem to work for me. `composer global remove drush/drush` does appear to run successfully.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its funny, yesterday I published a similar thread and deleted it after one of the users told me its a bug.

Comment: I reported it as bug in Drush github. Are you using WSL? Happened to me in WSL but not in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 22):

In my case, not all of the PHP packages made it though the Ubuntu upgrade to 16.04 (which now runs PHP 7 by default).  I needed to add the missing one, and then Drush started working again:

```
sudo apt install php-mysql
```

Or for php5 users

```
sudo apt install php5-mysql
```

on very recent Ubuntu/Debian distributions.

For PHP 7.1:

```
sudo apt install php7.1-mysql
```

For PHP 7.2:

```
sudo apt install php7.2-mysql
```

You can search for your version using this:

```
apt-cache search php-mysql
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. Just running sudo apt install php-mysql automatically installs the newest version

Answer (score 1):

Went down a bit of a rabbit hole on this one, but I believe the issue was related to drush connecting to the proper version of mysql. It needs the XAMPP version, not my local linux version. Adding these two lines to ~/.bashrc helped:

```
export DRUSH_PHP=/opt/lampp/bin/php

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem on Fedora 25.
i had upgraded to php 5.6.32 from 5,60,30 and neglected a switch in the compile of 32.

doing php -m showed that 5.6.32 neglected to have module "pdo_mysql". So i reverted back to 5.6.30 that has that module compiled in, until i can debug the 5.6.32 compile.

after this change Drush 8 worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the most up-to-date extensions for your version of PHP. You can find a list of the basic items you should install in the comments on the [PHP documentation site](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.php) under the upgrade to 7.1.

They recommend running: 
`sudo apt-get install php7.1 php7.1-cli php7.1-common libapache2-mod-php7.1 php7.1-mysql php7.1-fpm php7.1-curl php7.1-gd php7.1-bz2 php7.1-mcrypt php7.1-json php7.1-tidy php7.1-mbstring php-redis php-memcached`

If you don't, you will at very least run into issues with mbstring as this is a core dependency. This is also a potential solution for the all-too-common error "easyrdf/easyrdf 0.9.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system." when we run `composer install` for the first time. For different versions, just switch it out as appropriate. Most of them are likely the same.

Hope that helps someone.